# Using Tyrus Websocket Client in Android with Proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard, tyrus

I am trying to use Tyrus (org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles:tyrus-standalone-client:1.10) in Android. Here is my proguard related part:

```
-dontoptimize
-keepparameternames
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class org.glassfish.tyrus.** {  *; }
-keep class org.glassfish.grizzly.** { *; }
-keep class javax.websocket.** { *; }
```

I make a call to ClientManager connectToServer and this method doesnt return and hangs.But it works if i disable proguard. How can i make it work in Android with proguard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add following line for the Fragment or Activity that use Tyrus

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.package.YourClass$* { *; }
```

For tyrus you need to add following lines

```
-keepattributes Signature,InnerClasses,*Annotation*
-keep,includedescriptorclasses  class org.glassfish.tyrus.** {  *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses  class org.glassfish.grizzly.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses  class javax.websocket.** { *; }
```

By adding these lines, i managed to use Tyrus in Android.
Here is a reference for Tyrus: https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/reducing_websocket_client_jar_size